# How to send data from Server to Android Directly without invoking first from the android

Tags: android, android-c2dm, data-transfer

How can i send a data from Server to android directly without waiting for the request received from the Android. 
I have found one solution that is **C2DM** *but it require separate Google account to use it* **Now i am afraid if i install the same app on two different android will it work or not**

Plz suggest if u have some other mechanism.

Note: I dont want to use Network socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work. You need a gmail account registered for each android device AND a gmail account registered for sending out C2DM.

Alternatively you should make your own C2DM by polling your server at a regular interval (not recommended though).

Comment: but i can manage to have individual account for each device because it will be installed on too many devices

Comment: @WaseemKhan was that a question? If so plz improve grammar.

Comment: sorry i mean i cannot have individual account for each device so i do not want to use C2DM. is there any other way of doing this ?

Comment: If you want to send to all devices just give all devices the same id.